# Как превратить массив символов в строку

Tags: java, массивы

В строке содержатся слова с маленьких букв. Нужно заменить первые буквы слов, на большие.

Я решил сделать так:

1. Разбить строку на символы.
2. Заменить маленькие символы большими.
3. Массив символов превратить в строку. `char[] b;`

Я застрял на 3 шаге. Может кто написать как это сделать? Можно объяснением или блоком кода.

Comment: Все слова строки нужно писать с большой?

Comment: Да. В том и дело что символы я смог сделать большими, но как их объеденить в 1 строку, не знаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делать можно по-разному, конечно, но в Java есть методы для работы со строками. По-хорошему, нужно делать так:

1. Разбить строку по пробелам на слова и записать в массив
2. Пройтись по массиву, заменяя первые символы на символы верхнего
   регистра и складывая в одну строку.

Никаких массивов `char` использовать не нужно. Вам понадобятся следующие методы `String` и `Character`:

1. [split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) - делит строку на массив по какому-то правилу
2. [charAt(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) - возвращает символ по указанному индексу
3. [toUpperCase(char ch)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase-char-) - переводит в верхний регистр
4. [substring(int beginIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) - возвращает подстроку, начиная с
   указанного индекса

---

Если в строке есть несколько пробелов и их нужно учитывать при сборке текста обратно, то алгоритм будет такой:

Проходимся по строке:

1. Если символ на данной позиции пробел, то запоминаем это событие
2. Иначе, если символом на предыдущей позиции был пробел по Java
   (обычный пробел, табуляция и т.д.) либо начало строки, то заменяем
   его на символ верхнего регистра

   Вам понадобятся следующие методы `StringBuilder` и `Character`:

-

1. [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#length--) - возвращает длину строки
2. [charAt(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#charAt-int-) - возвращает символ на заданной позиции
3. [isWhitespace(char ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)) - проверяет, является ли символ пробелом по Java
4. [setCharAt(int index, char ch)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setCharAt-int-char-) - заменяет символ на заданной позиции на указанный
5. [toUpperCase(char ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)) - переводит в верхний регистр

Comment: `substring()` еще, скорее всего, пригодиться.

Comment: Благодарю, но я буквально с минуту назад нашел другое решение с помощью toCharArray(), а перевод осуществил с помощью Character.toString(b[i]). Конечно это было в цикле.

Comment: @IntFloat, верное замечание. Добавляю к ответу. Спасибо.

Comment: не понял как заносить в код

Comment: @Tayker, вы можете ответить на свой вопрос. Внизу есть синяя кнопочка.

Comment: @LEQADA, Пришло на ум что то вроде: `str[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+str[0].substring(1);`
если `str` массив слов после split

Comment: Там имеется еще 1 подводный камень который я не написал... количество пробелов может быть разным :)

Comment: @IntFloat, что-то я торможу. Вы правы. Можно и так `Character.toUpperCase(str[i].charAt(0)) + str[i].substring(1);`

Comment: @Tayker, это совсем не проблема `split()` выполняется с регулярным выражением в котором можно задать любые символы разделители.
Еще есть очень полезный класс `StringTokenizer`, он, по сути, является аналогом метода `split()`.

Comment: @IntFloat, со `split` проблема будет чуть другая. Понятно, что разбить по произвольному числу пробелов - тривиально. А вот собрать обратно с тем же числом пробелов между словами - уже сложнее. Т.е. Ваш метод из строки `aa_bb__ccc` сделает строку `Aa_Bb_Ccc`, где `_` я обозначаю пробел.

Comment: @andy.37, Вот именно поэтому я порекомендовал StringTokenizer, с помощью него можно разделить строку на лексемы с сохранением всех символов разделения.

Answer (score 2):

Эта операция называется `capitalize`, причем независимо от языка. Не зная Java вовсе, я загуглил `Java capitalize` и первая(!) ссылка дала:

```
WordUtils.capitalize(string)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java

Собственно, в одну строку без сторонних библиотек:

```
str = str.replaceAll("((^|\\s+)(\\w))", "$2\\u\\$3");
```

Честно говоря, не знаю, работает ли `\u` в Java, но можно так:

```
str = str.replaceAll("((^|\\s+)(\\w))", "$2" + "$3".toUpperCase());
```

Регулярка ищет либо первый буквенный символ в строке, либо букву, которая стоит за произвольным числом пробелов и приводит ее в верхний регистр, сохраняя то, что было перед ней (то самое число пробелов, либо ничего). Java у меня нет, тестил на perl, там работает.

П.С. внешние круглые скобки, вероятно, не нужны.

---

К сожалению, предложенный мной способ без `WordUtils` не сработает в Java по нескольким причинам. Задачка заинтересовала, поэтому приведу ее решение на паре других языков.

1) perl. Круче всего. Одна строчка. Даже функцию писать нет никакого смысла. perl, ИМХО, круче всех языков работает со строками:

```
my $s = "simple     string - example, а теперь   Русский текст";
$s =~ s/(\b\w)/\u$1/g;
print "$s\n";
```

2) python. (Решение в Java будет аналогичным, в 2.х Питоне работает только с английскими буквами, увы)

```
def capitalize(s):
    for g in re.finditer(r"^|\s+\w", s):
        s = s.replace(g.group(0), g.group(0).upper(), 1)
    return s


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = capitalize("my text solo\t\t\t\tstring\nmmm")
    print s
```

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что в этом решении требуется сторонняя библиотека `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3`, которую следует добавить в зависимости проекта.

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо, стоило конечно это отметить. Я больше к тому, что стоит знать стандартное название более-менее стандартной операции, и пользоваться гуглом.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
String s = reader.readLine();

char[] b = s.toCharArray();
if (b[0] != ' ') b[0] = Character.toUpperCase(b[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {

    if (b[i] == ' ' && b[i + 1] != ' ') {
        b[i + 1] = Character.toUpperCase(b[i + 1]);
    }
}

String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    result += Character.toString(b[i]);
}
```

Comment: И в правду... не задумывался над этим. Все из-за `(b[i+1])` или как?

Comment: Я чуть-чуть поправил ваш код. Надеюсь, вы не против :) Ответ может кому-то помочь в дальнейшем.

Comment: @LEQADA ну да :() так лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать прямо на вопрос, то нужно воспользоваться соответствующим [конструктором](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-):

```
String str = new String(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Стандартная операция

```
String s = b.toString();
```

Также преобразуется обратно

```
char[] b = s.toCharArray();
```

Comment: `b.toString()` и было использовано в коде

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне это самый легкий способ

Вот код:

```
char[] c = {'a','f','b'};
String s = new String(с);
```

Answer (score 0):

если нужно в строке текста каждый первый символ сделать из маленьких букв в большие то предлагаю такой вариант с пояснением: (может кому пригодится)

```
    String str1 = "hot, java";
    System.out.println( "рабочая строка : " + str1 );
    String[] array = str1.split( " " ); // заполняем массив типа  string словами
    System.out.println( "после сплита первое поле массива : " + array[0] );
    System.out.println( "после сплита второе поле массива : " + array[1] );
    System.out.println( "количество полей массива типа string : " + array.length );
    System.out.println( "проверка первого символа нулевого поля : " + array[0].charAt( 0 ) );
    System.out.println( "проверка первого символа первого поля : " + array[1].charAt( 0 ) );

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            char x = array[i].charAt( 0 ); // тогда присваиваем его переменной х типа char
            x = Character.toUpperCase( x ); // меняем на верхний регистр символ в переменной х
            array[i] = array[i].replace( array[i].charAt( 0 ), x ); // заменяем символ в нулевой позиции нужного поля на значение х типа char
        }
    }
    System.out.println( "после цикла первое поле массива :" + array[0] );
    System.out.println( "после цикла второе поле массива :" + array[1] );
    System.out.println( "теперь нужно билдером вернуть из массива строки в одну строку" );

    String finalstring = String.join( " ", array ); // разделяем пробелами при импорте в строку, т.к. сплит разбил по пробелам
    System.out.println( "конечный результат :" + finalstring );
```